# HTML5 "placeholder" support

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, placeholder

How can I find out if the browser supports the HTML5 placeholder tag, so I can decide whether to hook my jQuery placeholder plugin or not.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

```
var placeholderSupported = ( 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input') );
```

The variable `placeholderSupported` will be `true` if it is natively supported. Otherwise, it'll be set to `false`.

Comment: Why do you need !! in the expression?

Answer (score 16):

http://diveinto.html5doctor.com/everything.html#placeholder

```
return 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input');
```

However, the jQuery plugin you're using might already be checking for native support - you might *not* need to do this yourself.

Comment: jQuery support is simply; `$.support.placeholder`

Answer (score 4):

If you want to include third party libraries like Modernizr and yepnope.js, it's really easy to test for support and progressively enhance, gracefully degrade.

This is a good article with lots of resources that should help: http://www.sitepoint.com/regressive-enhancement-with-modernizr-and-yepnope/

Answer (score 2):

To get a broad idea go to:

http://caniuse.com/#search=placeholder

And to test in the browser you can do:

```
function supportsPlaceholder() {
  var i = document.createElement('input');
  return 'placeholder' in i;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I borrowed from the answer above and made it so that it is backwards compatible with older modern browsers as well as IE --

With the below code, make sure you have both a 'value' and 'placeholder' attribute set for the input fields.  In my particular case I needed to support IE variants.

Explanation -- If the browser supports placeholder the input value is removed.  If not, the older browsers will ignore the placeholder attributes and the below js mimics the default placeholder behavior.  This script will also ignore any auth tokens for CSRF (was getting an error where the auth token values were getting cleared in my forms causing a CSRF warning in my Rails apps).

Another approach to simplify the script itself is to assign a class to each input you specifically want to utilize this script and update the true statement accordingly (though the below method is a bit more dry).

```
var placeholderSupported = !!( 'placeholder' in document.createElement('input') );

if (placeholderSupported === true){
    $('input:not([type="submit"], [name="authenticity_token"])').val('');
} else{
    $('input')
      .focus(function() {
            if (this.value === this.defaultValue) {
                this.value = '';
            }
      })
      .blur(function() {
            if (this.value === '') {
                this.value = this.defaultValue;
            }
    });
}
```