# Placeholder text is not showing when using rails and bootstrap

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, ruby, twitter-bootstrap, placeholder

I am not sure why I can't see my **placeholder**.

I am using Rails and Bootstrap to generate the code:

```
= form_tag activity_path(@activity), method: :get do
  = text_field_tag :start_time," ", {placeholder: 'Start Date', class: 'pull-left input-small'}
  = text_field_tag :end_time," ", {placeholder: 'End Date', class: 'pull-left input-small'}
  %span.btn= submit_tag 'Show custom dates', class: 'btn'
```

Here is the generated code:

```
<input class="pull-left input-small" id="start_time" name="start_time" placeholder="Start Date" type="text" value=" " />

<input class="pull-left input-small" id="end_time" name="end_time" placeholder="End Date" type="text" value=" " />
```

The problem is that I can't see the placeholder. I tried setting it to a different color `input[placeholder] { color: ...}` but that didn't seem to work either. Any idea why this is happening? Thank you.

**[EDIT]**

I added `@placeholderText: #080808;` in my **bootstrap_and_overrides.css** file but that didn't seem to do the trick either.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're setting the value for both fields to " ", remove it, set both to nil

```
text_field_tag :start_time, nil, {placeholder: 'Start Date', class: 'pull-left input-small'}
```

Comment: Thank you! That was not very smart of me haha:D

Answer (score 0):

It might be your browser. As far as I know IE (9 and below) and Opera do not yet support the **placeholder** attribute yet. Firefox 3.7+ and Chrome/Safari 4.0+ should support it.

This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060265/html5-placeholder-support) and this [blog post](http://www.cssnewbie.com/cross-browser-support-for-html5-placeholder-text-in-forms/) have some good methods of working around it as well.

Comment: I am using chrome and firefox to test it but neither one of them work... Can't seem to figure out why... I think it might have something to do with bootstrap. I think I have to override the font from the bootstrap_and_overrides.css . Not sure what I am doing wrong though.