# Clear text with JavaScript in MVC 4

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I've the following search box:

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", "search...", new { @class = "SearchTxtBox" })
```

A text box with a default text "search...", I want to clear the text when the user enters the text box like we do in pure html:

```
<input type="text" value="search..." onfocus="if(this.value=='search...') this.value='';">
```

Any ideas how to do so in MVC 4?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to do the traditional way you cna do it this way:-

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", "search...", new { @class = "SearchTxtBox",onfocus="if(this.value=='search...') this.value='';" });
```

You can utilize HTML5 placeholder attribute too...

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString","", new { @class = "SearchTxtBox", placeholder = "search..." });
```

**Be aware of the fact that it is not supported in older browsers**

If you want to know more about its support and workaround you can go through the below thread.

[HTML5 "placeholder" support](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7060265/html5-placeholder-support)

Answer (score 1):

you don't have to use javascript to clear default text of textbox,you can use property of Html5's **PlaceHolder**

Try  this

```
@Html.TextBox("SearchString", new { @class = "SearchTxtBox" ,placeholder="search..."})
```